# jittery jQueryMobile controls

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I am using jQueryMobile for a project of mine.  I have a range control inside a collapsible-set inside of a jQueryMobile scrollview. On some of the ranges when they are selected, the entire scrollview/collapsible-set (i can't quite tell) jumps up about 150px, and I can no longer scroll to the top of the scrollview.  **How would you debug this?**  When I inspect the translate3d property, it seems to be ok.  I'll try to put together an example of this.

Comment: turns out the controls worked much better once the app was installed on the device, instead of running as a web app in the ios simulator.